# Exec Procedure who receive data from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Database in Oracle - View:

```
     COLUMN_NAME | DATE_TYPE
___________________________________________________
 UMOWA           | VARCHAR2(30)
 RODZ_LEAS       | VARCHAR2(1)
  KTH            | NUMBER(10)
  SKRÓT          | VARCHAR2(50)
 NAZWA           | VARCHAR2(240)
 AMORTYZ         | NUMBER(10,6)
 WALUTA          | VARCHAR2(3)
WARTOSC_UMW      | NUMBER
  LICZBA_RAT     | NUMBER
WK               | NUMBER
 WK%             | NUMBER
Rodzaj stopy baz.|  VARCHAR2(2000)
Wart.stopy baz.  | NUMBER
REFI             | NUMBER
RA_NR_RATY       | NUMBER(10)
RA_TYP           | VARCHAR2(10)
RA_DATA_SPLATY   | DATE
RA_KWOTA_NETTO   | NUMBER(12,2)
RA_KAPITAL_POZOSTALY   | NUMBER(12,2)
```

Procedure in SQL Server - it works - I get the data from Oracle.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [egeria].[ContractData_P] (@ContractNumberPar varchar(20))
AS
    EXECUTE(
        'Select 
            Umowa ContractNumber
            , Rodz_leas TypeOfLeasing
            , Kth CodeClient
            , skrót Short
            , Nazwa NameOfClient
            , amortyz Amortization
            , Waluta Currency
            , Wartosc_Umw ContractValue
            , Liczba_rat NumberOfInstallments
            , WK FinalValue
            , "WK%" FinalValuePercent
            , "Rodzaj stopy baz." TypeOfBaseRate
            , "Wart.stopy baz." ValueOfBaseRate
            , REFI
            , ra_nr_raty InstallmentNumber
            , ra_typ Type
            , ra_data_splaty MaturityDate
            , ra_kwota_netto NetAmount
            , ra_kapital_pozostaly CapitalRemaining
        from RAPADM.XLS_SKROCENIA_UMOW_V 
        where UMOWA  = ?'
        , @ContractNumberPar) AT EF_EG5PROD
GO
```

Model

```
public class ContractData
{
    public string ContractNumber { get; }
    public string TypeOfLeasing { get; }
    public int CodeClient { get; }
    public string Short { get; }
    public string NameOfClient { get; }
    public decimal Amortization { get; }
    public string Currency { get; }
    public decimal ContractValue { get; }
    public decimal NumberOfInstallments { get; }
    public decimal FinalValue { get; }
    public decimal FinalValuePercent { get; }
    public string TypeOfBaseRate { get; }
    public decimal ValueOfBaseRate { get; }
    public decimal REFI { get; }
    public decimal InstallmentNumber { get; }
    public string Type { get; }
    public DateTime MaturityDate { get; }
    public decimal NetAmount { get; }
    public decimal CapitalRemaining { get; }
}
```

Context

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ContractData> ContractData { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContractData>().HasNoKey();          
    }
}
```

ContractDataService -- HERE I HAVE ERROR

```
private readonly AppDbContext _context;

public ContractDataService(AppDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<ContractData>> ExecAsync(string contractNumberPar)
{
    var data = _context.ContractData.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE [egeria].[ContractData_P] @ContractNumberPar", contractNumberPar).AsEnumerable();
    return data;
}
```

Error:

> system.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements at
> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException() at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.Max(IEnumerable`1 source) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression
> binaryExpression) at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node) at
> System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitBlockExpressions(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor, BlockExpression block) at
> System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBlock(BlockExpression
> node) at
> System.Linq.Expressions.BlockExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor
> visitor) at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression
> node) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression
> extensionExpression) at
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node) at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression
> shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache,
> LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId) at

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Should I go another way?

Please check if what I am doing has any sense, or is it not better to go a better way?

Comment: This should really be whittled down to a minimal reproducible example ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Both because it makes the question easier to digest for potential answerers, and because reducing the faulty code should be the first approach which can already help pinpoint or even identify the problem.

Comment: `ContractData` has no setters for properties. EF cannot create appropriate mapper.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv
 how can I create such a mapping?

Comment: Add setters to properties. They all are read-only.

Comment: can I ask you for a code sample?

Comment: Add `set` - sample property `public string ContractNumber { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core cannot create projection expression because all properties of `ContractNumber` are readonly. Add setters to solve your issue:

```
public class ContractData
{
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfLeasing { get; set; }
    public int CodeClient { get; set; }
    public string Short { get; set; }
    public string NameOfClient { get; set; }
    public decimal Amortization { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public decimal ContractValue { get; set; }
    public decimal NumberOfInstallments { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalValue { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalValuePercent { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfBaseRate { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueOfBaseRate { get; set; }
    public decimal REFI { get; set; }
    public decimal InstallmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime MaturityDate { get; set; }
    public decimal NetAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal CapitalRemaining { get; set; }
}
```